# Method threw 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException' exception with autowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(myBean)

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection

I have an interface as decompile class called IOfferService.

I want to use without traditional dependency injection such as construct injection or with Autowired annotation.

Above the class, i defined

> private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory;

And in my method, i try to generate bean like following code.

```
   IOfferService offerService = (IOfferService) autowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(IOfferService.class);
   final List<Long> hidedOffers = offerService.inquireOfferIdListByOffer(SOMEENUMCLASS.enumValue);
```

But when i write this code and run, i got an error

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException' exception.
```

How can i fix this.?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use constructor injection please declare field as final then it will work.

`private final AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory`